# FIWare KeyRock: How to prevent fiware labs data being created when a new user registers

Tags: fiware

We want to use the FIWARE IdM, both Keystone and Horizon. Specifically during sign-up we want to

- create a user
- add that user to an organisation
- authorise the user for an application

We have installed Keystone and Horizon using the latest KeyRock docker image on the docker hub.
When a new user signs up:

- a 'cloud organisation' is created.
- By default, the 'provider' and 'purchaser' roles are present
- and the 'Store' application is assigned to the user (although i cannot verify this).
- We can add the user to an organisation by hand, and authorise the user for an application by hand in the KeyRock UI.

However this does not make any sense for our local installation.

1. How can we prevent Horizon from creating the cloud organisation upon user sign-up?
2. How can we assign a default application authorization upon user sign-up?

#### -- Edit --

It’s becoming increasingly clear to me that the way KeyRock is implemented is primarily useful for setting up your own Fiware labs environment, as opposed to setting up a generic Identity management service. If we use KeyRock, we will be stuck with cloud organisations, stores etc. Far from being a Generic Enabler (GE), KeyRock seems to be a “Fiware Labs” specific enabler.

All the GE documentation references KeyRock as the reference Identity Management GE. Therefore we (and i assume others too) have followed the documented architecture and configuration to link to KeyRock from:

- Wilma PEP Proxy GE
- Wirecloud Application Mashup GE

Because of the inbuilt Fiware Labs functions of KeyRock, we are having a really hard time applying Wilma PEP Proxy and Wirecloud Application Mashup to our use cases.
If we decide to use Keystone instead, we will lose

- OAuth2 support
- Permissions
- sign-up, admin and login screens.

Is anyone else having this problem?
How have they tackled it?

#### -- SCIM API --

Attempt at using the SCIM API is described here: [Fiware KeyRock SCIM API bug: _check_allowed_to_get_and_assign() got an unexpected keyword argument 'userName'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094473/fiware-keyrock-scim-api-bug-check-allowed-to-get-and-assign-got-an-unexpecte)

Comment: I tried editing /horizon/openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py such as suggested installation guide but that did not seem to have much effect on the above behaviour.

Comment: The SCIM extentions API (http://docs.keyrock.apiary.io/#reference/keystone-extensions/consumers/list-consumers) is an alternative, but then i need to create my own sign-up screens. Is that the recommended approach?

Comment: Using the SCIM extentions API gets me quite far, but it is not very clear what KeyRock needs in the way of role assignments to recognize a user. Also the userName attribute is unique and essential to login to KeyRock (but not created by the Keystone user creation API call) The admin user can view my newly created user but shows the following message "The user has no Cloud Project. Please contact an administrator". Why does a user on my machine need a cloud project?

Comment: Hi Robin, many thanks for your suggestions. We are working on making Keyrock more generic by separating the existing dependencies with FIWARE Lab. But this is a very big component and the work is not easy. However, as you can check we improve that behaviour in every new release. If you have problems with some specific part of the code, we will of course help you. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Alvaro, can you please comment on the above SCIM call error?