# Fiware KeyRock SCIM API bug: _check_allowed_to_get_and_assign() got an unexpected keyword argument 'userName'

Tags: fiware

We want to use the FIWARE IdM, both Keystone and Horizon. Specifically during sign-up we want to

- create a user
- add that user to an organisation
- authorise the user for an application

We have installed Keystone and Horizon using the latest KeyRock docker image on the docker hub (https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/idm/).

Because the KeyRock web interface creates Cloud organisations, community users in regions like Spain etc i decided to try to use the SCIM API to create and authorize users:

*Note*: The SCIM API documents (http://docs.keyrock.apiary.io/#reference/scim-2.0) imply the SCIM calls are on the KeyRock server port, however they are available on the Keystone server port. The SCIM documentation would be clearer if it mentioned http://[keystone server]/v3/OS-SCIM/v2/Users/ instead of http://keyrock/v3/OS-SCIM/v2/Users/

Lets say we have an application (SCIM consumer) with application_id=app1. This application is created using the Horizon front-end, or using the

```
    POST /v3/OS-OAUTH2/consumers
```

call. I am not aware of a difference between the two ways of creating an application although i have not tried the latter yet. This is a one-time operation, so we used the web interface to create the application and associated role.

so we have a role for the application = role1

and we create a user using SCIM

```
POST /v3/OS-SCIM/v2/Users/
```

that yields user_id=user1

When i try to authorize him for our application with

```
PUT /v3/OS-ROLES/users/user1/applications/app1/roles/role1
```

i get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
    "message": "_check_allowed_to_get_and_assign() got an unexpected keyword argument 'userName'",
    "code": 400,
    "title": "Bad Request"
    }
}
```

The next step would be to obtain a resource owner token through KeyRock using

```
POST [KeyStone server]/oauth2/token
```

But that is moot because of the above error.

Logging into the KeyRock user interface with user1 gives the error:
"You are not authorized for any projects." I assume this is because user1 is not authorized for an organisation. user1 is invisible to other users or the admin in the KeyRock user interface so i cannot assign the necessary authorizations.

Any ideas anyone?
Which roles does user1 still need to have and how to assign them so that KeyRock is satisfied?

Comment: I Robin, we are still working on this to provide you a solution.

Comment: It's been a month since my question. Any updates or insights into workarounds?

Comment: Its now been two months and we are still not able to programmatically create a user using the SCIM API. Is anyone working on this? Should we abandon the SCIM API?

Comment: We hope it will be fixed this week.

Answer (score 1):

After looking deep into your issue, it turns out that it might be related to the **lack of the new user's default organization**. Even though requests to SCIM API Users endpoint should create only users, it is certain that KeyRock users have internally a default organization, which cannot be seen from the outside. Since it makes sense to create this organization automatically as well, we just made a few improvements in the SCIM controller at KeyRock that take charge of this. You can take a look at the changes in [our GitHub repository](https://github.com/ging/keystone/commit/91805516c54661e3a937d6de114b8ae596ce0535).

I myself made sure that this should solve your issue, by following the same flow (note that the value of the `X-Auth-Token` header is an **admin** token and that the `Host` header should be your Keystone endpoint):

1. **Register a user** through SCIM API:

   ```
   POST /v3/OS-SCIM/v2/Users HTTP/1.1
   Host: localhost:5000
   Accept: */*
   Content-Type: application/json
   X-Auth-Token: 6bd914d9976c448a98b83ccaf5931c4e
   Content-Length: 55

   {
     "userName": "foo@foo.bar",
     "password": "foobar"
   }
   ```

   Which returns the following response:

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 201 Created
   Vary: X-Auth-Token
   Content-Type: application/json
   Content-Length: 276

   {
     "userName": "foo@foo.bar",
     "urn:scim:schemas:extension:keystone:2.0": {
       "domain_id": "default",
       "default_project_id": "c590cea2b37c4f1c9ca94a015837cde9"
     },
     "active": true,
     "id": "foo-foo-bar",
     "schemas": [
       "urn:scim:schemas:core:2.0",
       "urn:scim:schemas:extension:keystone:2.0"
     ]
   }
   ```
2. **Authorize the newly created user** for the application `app1` by assigning them the role `role1`:

   ```
   PUT /v3/OS-ROLES/users/foo-foo-bar/applications/app1/roles/role1 HTTP/1.1
   Host: localhost:5000
   Accept: */*
   Content-Type: application/json
   X-Auth-Token: fd817b31444141a7a8a15d6d6afd2078
   ```

   Which in turn returns the following success response:

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
   Vary: X-Auth-Token
   Content-Length: 0
   ```
3. After this, I was finally able to **obtain a resource owner OAuth2 token**, as you requested (the `Authorization` header includes the OAuth2 credentials of `app1`).

   ```
   POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
   Host: localhost:8000
   Accept: */*
   Authorization: Basic 12345678abcdefgh=
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   Content-Length: 56

   grant_type=password&username=foo@foo.bar&password=foobar
   ```

   And the token is at last returned:

   ```
   HTTP/1.0 200 OK
   Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie
   Content-Type: application/json

   {
     "access_token": "JYjCV2H8QNakRPUqqdoAHZmpmD0vgQ",
     "token_type": "Bearer",
     "expires_in": 3600,
     "refresh_token": "snnS8djsYw62aUtl9Szk9BBqti36jF"
   }
   ```